# GET http://localhost/laravel-filemanager?field_name=mceu_47-inp&type=Images 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel

I installed laravel file manager step by step. But when I try to upload an image then it shows this error message below.

[image: error]

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: Maybe no one can help you. Because, lack of information. Include some code in question's description.

Comment: Do you have controller method that handles this request?Do you already setup route properly? add those codes in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class above the App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class :

```
  /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,

    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
    Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class,
```

This way, on a request, it will first check the routes from the filemanager and if there is no hit it will go to your routes.php. Now it will go through your routes.php and if it has a catchall route (to catch remaining request that do not have an absolute path or do not match any of your routes) it will end up in the cathcall route en won't be able to even reach the routes of the filemanager.

Comment: thanks for the reply! but after adding this I'm getting the new error. Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider' not found.